# Execution flow of a linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

case1

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add (1);
IEnumerable<int> query = numbers.Select (n => n * 10);    // Build query
numbers.Add (2);

//Use or execute query
```

case2

```
var numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
numbers.Add(4);
List<int> query  = numbers
  .Select (n => n * 10) 
  .ToList();                      // Executes immediately into a List<int>
numbers.Add(3);
numbers.Clear();

//Use or execute query
```

Why in the first case query contains both 1,2

In second case query contains only 1,2,4 but not 3,is it because we are calling .ToList() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the query is not executed until you start enumerating over the resultset (by either calling .ToArray(), .ToList(), or simply write a foreach)

```
IEnumerable<int> query = numbers.Select (n => n * 10);
```

doesn't execute anything. It's the the lazy nature of LINQ.

Comment: You can see this if you put a breakpoint on the code within the select. It'll break only once the query is being enumerated.

Answer (score 1):

Any Linq method that returns `IEnumerable<T>` is deferred, meaning it won't return items until enumerated.

`ToList<T>()` is a non-deferred operation.

Answer (score 0):

In `case1` query executed after you enumerated it.

In `case2` the result doesn't contain `3` because you've already executed the query and holding it's result (which is an `IEnumarable` object) in `query` variable (and it's not a `Linq Query` object.)

Answer (score 0):

linq uses the concept of late execution means it will execute the query only when it call for the actual work like .first .list etc.

Answer (score 0):

the linq will call the DB and return actul data only when .tolist() will call.